# PHP array to string conversion notice with CachingIterator

Tags: php, spl

I have done some searching on Stackoverflow already on this topic, however as far as I can tell, I am not treating an array as a string ?

The message I am getting is :

> Array to string conversion in X on line 42

Line 42 of my code is the opening of a `foreach` loop :

```
foreach ($collection as $element) {
```

Variable `$collection` is a caching iterator that is based on database output:

`$collection=new \CachingIterator(new \ArrayIterator($this->dbData));`

If I `print_r()` on `$this->dbData`, I certainly get an array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [c_id] => A
 )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [c_id] => B
)
```

So, in summary:

- We have a confirmed output of an array
- We know that `ArrayIterator()` expects an `array` as argument
- We know that `CachingIterator()` expects an `Iterator` as argument
- We know that `foreach()` can loop over an `Iterator`

*TL;DR* I am really not sure what I am treating as string here ?

**EDIT TO ADD....**

Even if I greatly simplify my code, I can still reproduce:

```
<?php
error_reporting (E_ALL | E_STRICT);
ini_set ('display_errors', 1);
$arrX=array(array("c_id"=>"A"),array("c_id"=>"B"));
$collection=new \CachingIterator(new \ArrayIterator($arrX));
foreach($collection as $element) {
echo $element["c_id"].PHP_EOL;
}
```

> Notice: Array to string conversion in /Users/bp/tmp/test.php on line 6
>
> A
>
> Notice: Array to string conversion in /Users/bp/tmp/test.php on line 6
>
> B

Comment: If you `var_dump( $collection );` what do you see?

Comment: It's you only who are sure about everything, but we are not. show use code and output of  `var_dump( $collection );`

Comment: I highly doubt that's the line generating the error.

Comment: Also, what comes immediately after your `foreach()` line?

Comment: If you put an `exit` just before the `foreach`, do you still get the error?

Comment: @PatrickMoore `$this->navData[]='<li>'.$element["c_id"].'</li'>`

Comment: @David `exit` before `foreach` is going to be easier said than done.  It yields a blank page but that's only probably because it breaks  the bigger picture (this is a class function that generates an HTML menu that gets passed to `slim/twig-view` as part of `slim/slim`).    The HTML menu gets generated perfectly, no problems, only these PHP NOTICE messages which seem to have no negative effect on the ultimate output.

Comment: @AlivetoDie see sample code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer is, you're inadvertently asking the `CachingIterator` to convert the sub-arrays to strings during iteration.  To not do this, don't use the `CachingIterator::CALL_TOSTRING` or `CachingIterator::TOSTRING_USE_INNER` flags.

You can set no flags, by using `0` as the value for the `$flags` parameter, or use a different flag: this can be done in the constructor, or after initialisation by using `CachingIterator::setFlags()`.

For example:

```
$array = [["c_id" => "A"], ["c_id" => "B"]];
$collection = new CachingIterator(new ArrayIterator($array), 0);
foreach ($collection as $element) {
    // no E_NOTICE messages, yay!
}
```

---

And a few words by way of explanation...

By default, the `CachingIterator` class sets the `CachingIterator::CALL_TOSTRING` flag as noted in the [PHP manual page on `CachingIterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.cachingiterator.php).

> ```
> public __construct ( Iterator $iterator [, int $flags = self::CALL_TOSTRING ] )
> ```

When this flag (or the `CachingIterator::TOSTRING_USE_INNER` flag) is set, and the `CachingIterator::next()` method is called (i.e. during iteration) the current value (in this case each sub-array) or the inner iterator (in this case, the `ArrayIterator`), respectively, is converted to a string and saved internally.  This string value is what is returned from `CachingIterator::__toString()` when one of those flags is used.

When using any of the other flags, the above is not done when calling `CachingIterator::next()`.

Comment: Proper explanation and correct answer. I hope OP will look to this and then decide to choose best answer.

Comment: I have given this answer an up-vote.  I stand by my comment on the @MonkeyZeus answer about that poster being the first to provide an answer instead of snarky comments.   I will leave it to MonkeyZeus as to whether they are prepared to concede their answer status.  If the answer is positive, I'll come back and do the deed.  Otherwise I will leave it as "first answered, first scored" basis.

Comment: That's very charitable of you, @LittleCode.  If this answer helped you, and shows up in search results for others experiencing the same issue, that's all that really matters. :-)

Comment: @LittleCode This is a really good answer and does quite a great job of explaining the situation. Feel free to accept whichever answer you think helped you the most and will help future readers. It is always safe to ignore loud users that get on their high horse for some reason. Additionally, I do admit that your minimal sample code was the only reason that I was able to answer your question; otherwise, I was just gonna upvote and move along since your question did not seem trivial but I had no knowledge of that class.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus thanks. I have re-allocated the answer.  But I want to stress that it was *ONLY* because of the extra detail.  I have ZERO interest in bowing to loud users on their high horses, I don't care for peer pressure.  I made an objective decision based only on the answers presented.  Thanks to both of the answers.

Answer (score 1):

You need `CachingIterator::FULL_CACHE` per [this PHP docs comment](http://php.net/manual/en/class.cachingiterator.php#120081)

```
<?php
$arrX = array(
    array( "c_id" => "A" ),
    array( "c_id" => "B" )
);
$collection = new \CachingIterator( new \ArrayIterator( $arrX ), CachingIterator::FULL_CACHE );
foreach( $collection as $element )
{
    echo $element["c_id"].PHP_EOL;
}
```